# Geodesics in a connected surface S parametrized by arc length with constant binormal vector implies that S are open of planes and spheres?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, geodesic

**Question:** Geodesics in a connected surface S parametrized by arc length  with constant binormal vector implies that S are open of planes and spheres?

**My idea:** I know that binormal vector is defined by $b=t\times n=\alpha '\times\frac{\alpha ''}{k}$.

On the other hand, it is true that if all geodesics in a connected surface are plane curves, then this surface is a subset of a plane or a sphere. I know how to prove this too. Thus, I'm trying to find a way to connect the question above with this result.

However I'm not so sure if this is the best idea. I even do not know if the question above is true because I didn't find any counterexample. Would you help me with this?

Comment: You don't need to go back to the definition of the binormal at this point. Why are you not considering the relevant Frenet equation?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin You're totally right! I thought I would connect this definition with $k_g=\langle \alpha'', N\wedge \alpha' \rangle $ and $K^2= k_{g}^{2}+k_{n}^{2}$. But, did not work. I don't know how to solve so.